# BigQuery - JSON selecting n-th item

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

BigQuery audit logs JSON entry is built in a way that the second item has different key depending on the operation it pertains to. The documentation calls it "Union field event", which means only one is present.

```json
  // Union field event can be only one of the following:
  "jobInsertion": {
    object (BigQueryAuditMetadata.JobInsertion)
  },
  "jobChange": {
    object (BigQueryAuditMetadata.JobChange)
  },
  "jobDeletion": {
    object (BigQueryAuditMetadata.JobDeletion)
  },
  "datasetCreation": {
    object (BigQueryAuditMetadata.DatasetCreation)
  },
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata

The problem is that in order to get this object in BigQuery SQL, one would need to code it separately like this:

```sql
  JSON_EXTRACT(PARSE_JSON(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson), '$.jobChange'),
  JSON_EXTRACT(PARSE_JSON(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson), '$.jobInsertion'),
  JSON_EXTRACT(PARSE_JSON(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson), '$.tableDataRead '),
```

And then somehow unify it. I wonder if there's a way to just select second item of the followig JSON:

```json
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata",
  "tableDataRead": {
    "fields": [
      "insertId",
      "logName",
      "protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson",
      "protopayload_auditlog.methodName",
      "receiveTimestamp",
      "resource.labels.dataset_id",
      "resource.labels.location",
      "resource.labels.project_id",
      "resource.type",
      "severity"
    ],
    "jobName": "projects/element-analytics-dev-poc/jobs/job_XvacfHSAAr_Og7zQFVNV9ioV9vfu",
    "reason": "JOB"
  }
}
```

I couldn't find a function in BigQuery that would let me do that but maybe I missed something? If there's no function, I'm assuming I would need to create JavaScript UDF?